# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' was called on null

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:Trial/app/services/auth.dart';

class RegisterForm extends StatefulWidget {
  RegisterForm({@required this.auth});
  final AuthBase auth;

  @override
  _RegisterFormState createState() => _RegisterFormState();
}

class _RegisterFormState extends State<RegisterForm> {
  // final TextEditingController _firstnameController = TextEditingController();
//  final TextEditingController _lastnameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  //String get _fname => _firstnameController.text;
  //String get _lname => _lastnameController.text;
  String get _email => _emailController.text;
  String get _password => _passwordController.text;

  void _register() async {
    try {
      print('$_email & $_password');
      await widget.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  List<Widget> _buildChildren() {
    return [
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'First Name', hintText: 'John'),
      ),
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Last Name', hintText: 'Doe'),
      ),
      TextField(
        controller: _emailController,
        decoration:
            InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email', hintText: 'yourmail@mail.com'),
        onChanged: (_email) => _updateState(),
      ),
      TextField(
        controller: _passwordController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Password',
        ),
        obscureText: true,
        onChanged: (_password) => _updateState(),
      ),
      TextField(
        decoration:
            InputDecoration(labelText: 'Account No.', hintText: '123456789-0'),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 5.0,
      ),
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: ' MAP LOCATION'),
      ), //LOCATION CAPTURE GOING HERE
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Register'),
        onPressed: _register,
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: ListView(
        children: _buildChildren(),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _updateState() {
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is this

> I/flutter ( 6751): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' was called on null.
>
> I/flutter ( 6751): Receiver: null
> ?
> I/flutter ( 6751): Tried calling: createUserWithEmailAndPassword("test@gmail.com", "password")

I am fairly new at flutter and firebase. I am trying to register a user, but the method in the auth class is passing as null.

```
import 'package:Trial/app/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:Trial/app/signin/register_form.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RegisterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  RegisterPage({@required this.auth});
  final AuthBase auth;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Register Account'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Card(child: RegisterForm(auth: auth)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This will be my auth file

```
 import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class User {
  User({@required this.uid});
  final String uid;
}

abstract class AuthBase {
  Stream<User> get onAuthStateChanged;
  Future<User> currentUser();
  Future<User> signInAnonymously();
  Future<User> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
  Future<User> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
  Future<void> signOut();
}

class Auth implements AuthBase {
  /*to check to see if anyone is signed in*/
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User _userFromFirebsae(FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return User(uid: user.uid);
  }

  @override
  Stream<User> get onAuthStateChanged {
    return _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebsae);
  }

  @override
  Future<User> currentUser() async {
    final user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    return _userFromFirebsae(user);
  }

/*to sign in without logining in*/
  @override
  Future<User> signInAnonymously() async {
    final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
    return _userFromFirebsae(authResult.user);
  }

  @override
/*to sign in with email*/
  Future<User> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    return _userFromFirebsae(authResult.user);
  }

//create email
  @override
  Future<User> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    return _userFromFirebsae(authResult.user);
  }

/*to sign out of app*/
  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you initialize RegisterForm and pass `auth`

Comment: @SwiftiSwift i was trying to add it here but it wasn't formatting properly so I added it in the question it self to the bottom

Comment: show us where u pass the real `auth` parameter with the content. Where do u initialize `RegisterPage`

Comment: slightly confused is it not passing in  on the await widget.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);

Comment: We need to see where you are passing auth the first time.

Comment: I added the auth file but I was following a tutorial and he switch to bloc after a while, I am fairly new to this sorry if i'm not giving the information you need to help but I appreciate the effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've never initialized `auth` in:

```
class RegisterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  RegisterPage({@required this.auth});
  final AuthBase auth;
  ...
```

You'll want to initialize it to:

```
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

Comment: I import FirebaseAuth but i still got an error "A value of type 'FirebaseAuth' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AuthBase'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'AuthBase'."  and in the required I got an error 'auth' is final and was given a value when it was declared, so it can't be set to a new value.
Try removing one of the initializations.

Comment: Yeah, you'll want to change the field to be `FirebaseAuth`, to match with the [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage). I updated that in my answer.

Comment: hey i already try that when i change it the RegisterPage({@required this.auth}); the auth gave this error 'auth' is final and was given a value when it was declared, so it can't be set to a new value.
Try removing one of the initializations.

Comment: Hey thanks man I got through I had to take out the required and then pass the values to the createwithemailandpassword method and it created a user and log in I don't too much understand how it work but I hope I can understand it so I can build something good in the future